# How to disable ng-grid enter event? (And override it)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid, keyevent

I have ng-grid table. And I try to navigate and do some action by keyboard. But first trouble is how to disable ng-grid "enter" event?

I try to catch all event

```
$scope.mySelections_data_list = [];
$scope.gridoptions_data_list = {
       columnDefs: 'columnDefsDataList',
       data: 'data_list',
       headerRowHeight: 35,
       multiSelect: false,
       rowHeight: 35,
       selectedItems: $scope.mySelections_data_list
};

$scope.keyPress = function(eve){
       console.log(eve.which);
};
```

But keypress dont catch busy (by ng-grid) events.

Template:

```
<div class="gridStyle" 
 ng-grid="gridoptions_class_list" 
 ng-keydown="keyPress($event);"
 ></div>
```

Thanks for help!